# Ajax MySQL "Unexpected token <"

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I want to do simply thing, get table from MySQL database.
Earlier i had no MySQLi code, simple MySQL and it was working. Now, after change to MySQLi i got error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I have this code:

AJAX:

```
("#load-all").click(function(){
    $.ajax({   
        type: "GET",
        url: "akceptAPI.php",             
        dataType: "text",             
        success: function(response){ 
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                datatable = data;
                generateTable(data);                  
                bindTr();
            },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

AkceptAPI.php (request)

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("connect.php");

//MySQLi query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oczekujace");
//get all records from add_delete_record table
$array = array();
$tempArray = array();
while($row = $results->mysql_fetch_row())
{
    $tempArray = $row;
 // $array[]= array("ID"=>$row[0],"Nazwa"=>$row[1],"Autor"=>$row[2],"Cena"=>$row[3],"Opis"=>$row[4],"JSON_DATA"=>$row[5]);
    array_push($array,$tempArray)
}

echo json_encode($array);
//close db connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = 'obrazypol'; //databasename

//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

?>
```

Comment: `while($row = $results->mysql_fetch_row()) `? mixing mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syantax error. semicolon missing after array_push function.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
//MySQLi query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category");
//get all records from add_delete_record table
$array = array();
$tempArray = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_row())
{
   $tempArray = $row;
    // $array[]=       array("ID"=>$row[0],"Nazwa"=>$row[1],"Autor"=>$row[2],"Cena"=>$row[3],"Opis"=>$row[4],"JSON_DATA"=>$row[5]);
   array_push($array,$tempArray);
}

echo json_encode($array);
//close db connection
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while($row = $results->fetch_row())
```

instead of

```
while($row = $results->mysql_fetch_row())
```

Comment: Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\picturesoflight\akcept\akceptAPI.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />   now getting this error, i cant see what is wrong oO

Comment: `<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("connect.php");

//MySQLi query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oczekujace");
//get all records from add_delete_record table
$array = array();
$tempArray = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_row())
{
 $tempArray = $row;
 array_push($array,$tempArray)
}
echo json_encode($array);

//close db connection
$mysqli->close();
?>`

Comment: use ; after this line array_push($array,$tempArray)

Comment: @Sko: if you switch to an IDE (e.g. NetBeans, Eclipse, PHP Storm) you'll have that sort of error highlighted for you in your editor.

Comment: Ok, now is working. That was stupid error... thanks.

Comment: You are welcome and please follow @halfer sugession.